# Why do two arrays share values?

Tags: python, list, swap

I have an array `array1 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]` and I want to switch `array1[0]` and `array1[1]`, which would ideally look like this: `array1 = [[4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3]]`. So far I have tried this:

```py
array1 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
array2 = array1
array1[0] = array2[1]
array1[1] = array2[0]
```

But that returns `[[4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7]]`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `array2 = array1` just means that two names now refer to the same list.  In other words, names aren't memory locations, they're just labels attached to objects.

Comment: Use this to see what happens: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: You could just have used `array1[0], array1[1] = array1[1], array1[0]`.

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You don't have two arrays, you have one list with two names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
array1 = [array1[1], array1[0]]
```

Then you don't need `array2`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
array2 = array1
```

You are making it so `array2` references the same object in memory that `array1` does. This is called a "binding" assignment. After that the expression:

```
array1[0] = array2[1]
```

is no different than saying:

```
array1[0] = array1[1]
```

There no longer is any difference between array1 and array2.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to copy an array, but:

```
array2 = array1
```

is not copying. You just created a new label `array2` and pointed it to `array1`.

To copy an array, you can have a loop at `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html